# how to keep the leading zero's in an enum?

Tags: c++

i'm trying to store bytes of data in to an enum,

```
    enum bufferHeaders
{//output_input
    void_void = 0x0003010000,
    output_void = 0x00030B8000,
    void_input = 0x0006010000,
    led_on = 0xff1A01,
    led_off = 0x001A01,
};
```

the leading zero's of my values are being ignored and the compiler stores my values as int.

later I need to be able to find how many bytes each set of data exactly is.

Comment: Use literals. `0x0003010000ull` will make the type `unsigned long long`

Comment: Each element of an enum has the same type. They will all have the same number of bytes.

Comment: Leading zeroes don't affect an integer's value. You can still find out how many bytes are non-zero afterwards. Overall, very unclear question.

Comment: I think you should elaborate on why and `int` is "bad"

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the leading zeros and the size of the data matters to you? Generally these should be implementation details that don't affect the use of an `enum`. It's hard to determine what you should do without knowing exactly what your problem is.

Comment: @patatahooligan the leading zero's are meaningful for the usb device which receives the buffer. what I should be doing explicitly is using an unsigned char*[] in which each index takes one byte of data, but I really need a way around that.

Comment: @BehnamEzazi If every value you need to send has the same number of bits, just use a [fixed-size integer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Comment: @patatahooligan the size of the input buffers vary unfortunately.. but thank you I take that to consideration for another solution

Comment: @Yksisarvinen that wont cut it..

Answer (score 5):

If you write

```
enum bufferHeaders : int
{
    // ToDo - your values here
};
```

Then it's *guaranteed* that the backing type is `int`, so the number of bytes used to store each value is `sizeof(int)`. But then the onus is on you to make sure that the `enum` values can fit into an `int`: `0xff1A01` for example might not.

Numerically speaking, preserving leading zeros makes no sense at all.

Comment: Don't we need `enum class` (any more) to inherit from base types?

Comment: @Aconcagua: Nope, C++11 onwards allows you to specify a backing type for a "plain-old" enum.

Comment: yes, I also tried __int64 which stores up to 8 bytes of data, but that doesn't help my problem, and yes numerically speaking leading zero's mean nothing but I'm trying to create a buffer for a USB device and having exactly n leading zero's is important for my task.

Comment: @BehnamEzazi: That makes no sense. Leading zeros are *assumed* for an integer type to make up the bit width of that type.

Comment: @Behnam then enums are simply the wrong tool for the job. Every Element of an enum will have the same size.

Comment: @Voo what do you suggest?

Comment: @Behnam There many possible designs but at the end it'll have to be an array with explicit size. std::array would probably be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up numerical value and representation!

There are always multiple ways to represent one and the same value: 77, 0x4d, 0x04d (guess, it is my birth year). I won't get older just because you change the representation.

Internally, the CPU has its own representation for a value, which is a specific bit pattern in one if its registers (or somewhere in RAM).

When printing out integer or enum values to console, the internal representation of the CPU is converted to some default representation suitable for most situations. If you want to have another representation, you need to explicitly tell which formatting to apply to retrieve such a representation:

```
    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << std::internal << std::setfill('0')
              << std::setw(10) << 77 << std::endl;
```

Be aware that the stream modifiers above all but `std::setw` modify the stream persistently (until next modification), so you need to explicitly revert if you want to have different output format subsequently, whereas `std::setw` only applies for next value to be output and has to be re-applied for every subsequent value.

Comment: Just to avoid panic, the formatting flags are **sticky**, i.e., they stay in effect until changed. That's not quite "permanent". <g>

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific need for you to use enums? By default every value will have the same type and you seem to be focused on the numerical value stored. If you are really concerned about the representation it might be a good approach to leave the enum as int and storing the values in a `std::map` structure where you can use the enum value as the key itself and the value will be the numerical value whichever way you want to store it.

Comment: that is quite smart and might do the trick but what do you suggest for the leading zero's problem? I could do as you said and store the numerical values inside char[] and use the enum value as the key to reach them, but I have different length in my numerical values. what is your opinion? would you still consider this a good approach?

Comment: also everything in the class im writing this solution must be static and be accessible without an instance of the object.

Comment: Having all the values in a static map won't be an issue, you can just declare it globally. It's not an approach I'm fond of but in case of such a need it seems to be the way to go. If you can use the std namespace the best approach might be to use `std::string` for the values of the map. The length won't be an issue and it'll be easily accessible.